# Gradle equivelant of maven repository management paramenter

Tags: maven, gradle

When building with Gradle I would like to reuse the maven repository I created in the past for dependency management, it is basically working, but I cannot find out answers for below questions from Gralde official document:

1. Does Gradle reuse my settings.xml from default location (my home folder) during maven dependency resolution?
2. How could I specify a repository in Gradle instead of using the default one? I can do it in maven command with -Drepository parameter easily.
3. How to control the update policy? I mean always update snapshot dependency and update release dependency per week something like this, or is my setting in settings.xml takes effect to Gradle as well?

Thanks in advance.

B.R.

Answer (score 2):

My answers below are based on the following chapters from gradle user guide:

- [8. DEPENDENCY MANAGEMENT BASICS](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)
- [51. DEPENDENCY MANAGEMENT](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html)

Now, to the specific answers:

1. According to [DEPENDENCY MANAGEMENT BASICS](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) (section 51.6.4. Local Maven repository), I guess the answer to this question would be yes:

> Gradle uses the same logic as Maven to identify the location of your
>   local Maven cache. If a local repository location is defined in a
>   settings.xml, this location will be used. The settings.xml in
>   USER_HOME/.m2 takes precedence over the settings.xml in M2_HOME/conf.
>   If no settings.xml is available, Gradle uses the default location
>   USER_HOME/.m2/repository.

This applies to local repository defined as:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

2. Sections [8.5. Repositories](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10621) and [51.6. Repositories](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories) in gradle user guide describes a couple of ways to define the repositories you'd like to use. these includes using `mavenCentral`, specifying a remote custom Maven repository, e.g.: `maven { url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2" }`, etc. If you'd like to pass the repository via command line then you can use gradle [system property](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) for that.
3. I believe that section [51.9. THE DEPENDENCY CACHE](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_cache) contains the information you're looking for. In short, the default cache is for 24 hours. However, it can be overridden configuring the [ResolutionStrategy](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html), e.g.: `resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10, 'minutes'`. 
   Regarding using the settings in settings.xml then I could not find a clear answer for that but you're welcome to give it a try :)

Comment: Thanks Amnon for the descriptive information! Question for item 2, it looks like even Gradle reuse .m2/settings.xml to get maven local repository, it just treats it as another repository, it will never reuse the maven remote repository configuration in settings.xml for dependency download. I still have to explicitly declare maven remote repository in gradle for dependency resolution and update. It looks weird to me, any tricks to leverage maven remote repository in gradle?